# Where should .db files be installed by the application?

Tags: sql, c, linux, database, sqlite

I'm building an application that uses .db sqlite databases. However I don't know where the program should install these files into the users computer in Linux. usr/share doesn't allow the program to modify the database.

Comment: If the data in these files should only be accessible by one user, then the ~/.your_app_name/  can be a place to store them.

Comment: I mean only the program would be accessing that file. That counts as one user right?

Comment: Yes, if the program is only run by a single user, then the program should just use $HOME variable as a base directory for file storage. If you need a program that is run by different users, but the program accesses the same file, then you have to delve into user permissions and user groups (create a group for the program, add your user to the group, allow the file in /usr/share/ to be modified by that user group).